# Tkinter animate Label text as a html marque

Tags: python, animation, tkinter

I want a text to move first to East and then to West and so on...
The code i trying

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk(className='Papinhio player')
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
#now playing bar
now_playing = tk.Label(root,text="Some text",anchor="w")
now_playing.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=20,padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=10,ipady=10)
#now_playing.config(width=root.winfo_screenwidth()-32)

global empty_characters
global now_playing_state
now_playing_state = "right"
empty_characters = ""

def animate_now_playing():
    print("Running!")
    text = "Some text"
    global empty_characters
    global now_playing_state
    current_width = now_playing.winfo_width()
    available_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()

    print("Current width: "+str(current_width))
    print("Available width: "+str(available_width))

    if(now_playing_state=="right"):
        if(current_width<available_width):
            empty_characters+= " "
        else:
            now_playing_state="left"
    if(now_playing_state=="left"):
        if(len(empty_characters)!=0):
            empty_characters = empty_characters[:-1]
        else:
            now_playing_state="right"

    now_playing.config(text=empty_characters+text)
    root.after(40, animate_now_playing)



# display the menu
#root.config(menu=menubar)

#root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


root.after(100, animate_now_playing)
root.mainloop()
```

**Code edited:**

The text is moving to East and then to West
But now it's a offset issue.

How can i fix?

Thanks in advance,

Chris Pappas

Comment: What's your expectation?It could run normally on my PC.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA In Ubuntu (20.04) `root.winfo_screenwidth()` returns `1024`. But i have a sidebar with programms in ubuntu so root.winfo_screenwidth() is less than 1024

Comment: I tried to put it inside a frame. I also remove padx, pady ipadx, ipady. Same error.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA the problem is that 1024. How can i fix it?
I see the expected result, but something wrong in numbers.

Comment: How many monitors do you have hooked to your computer?

Comment: Just one.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced the code below that worked for me. I can size the window and the moving text stays within it.

```
available_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
# Replace With
available_width = root.winfo_width()
```

Comment: It's worked! But i have to do `available_width = root.winfo_width()-14`. Explanation: 2*padx+2*border width+2(unknown)=14. Thanks!